# Actual name of the type of code

Tags: c#

So I basically taught myself how to program (I didn't say I was any good), and I'm curious of what the names are for codes, it's hard for me to explain.

```
Console.WriteLine( "eg." );
   ^  and   ^
```

I was wondering what they were called? Is it something like method and function? O.o

Comment: "[Static] Class" ([`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43zwz7ys.aspx)) and "[Static] Method" ([`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5.aspx)). (That syntax depends on context, however, and it is possible to write the same code in a different context where those same parts "represent different things" such a Properties.)

Comment: You can get more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left hand side of the code you listed before the period is the **class**. In this case the class is **Console**.

The right hand side of the period is a **method**. In this case, **WriteLine()**.

This is an example of a **static method** call, because you did not instantiate an object of type **Console**, but rather just called a static method from that class.

Answer (score 2):

- `Console` is short for `System.Console`. It's a class named `Console` in the `System` namespace.
- `WriteLine` is a method within the `Console` class.

---

I would *strongly* suggest you start with some beginner's material. If you don't know what these things are called, you're going to find it impossible to learn anymore. All tutorial material will assume that you've at least heard of a class.